# SQL query returns multiple rows instead of just one row

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

```
select 
    t.customer_type,
    (case 
         when &a1 in (1, 2) and &a2 in ('AZN', 'USD', 'ALL') 
             then (select t.balance_no from test12 t 
                   where t.customer_type = &a1 and t.currency = &a2)
         when &a1 in (1, 2) and &a2 not in ('AZN', 'USD', 'ALL') 
             then (select t.balance_no from test12 t 
                   where t.customer_type = &a1 and t.currency = 'ALL') 
     end)
from 
    test12 t
where 
    t.customer_type = &a1
group by 
    t.customer_type;
```

In this query, if I don't use

```
where t.customer_type = &a1
group by t.customer_type
```

at the end, it returns as many rows as the number of rows in the table. I can't understand why. You know I wrote 'where t.customer_type=&a1 and t.currency=&a2' in the case statement.

Comment: What are you trying to show as output?  This is very confusing.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is one mechanism to reduce the number of rows  so that one row in your case customer_type  is produced. without  it, the query returns all rows that fir your where clause

Comment: The `case` expression (not statement!) returns something or other, depending on the condition; it does not "return the row" or "not return the row", as you seem to believe. The number of rows in the result of a query **never** depends on what is in the `select` clause; they should teach this in the first three or four lessons of basic SQL instruction.